# docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase error when running vhosts

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I run: `docker run -e jwilder/nginx-proxy  VIRTUAL_HOST=myadd.dev`

It returns:

`docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.`

`docker ps` returns:

container id: b1467ba0f2ae
image: jwilder/nginx-proxy

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ~/.certs:/etc/nginx/certs # I recomend to simplify you local workflow by using wildcard domain name ssl -> localhost(.key|.crt)
  nginx-localhost:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: nginx-localhost
    volumes:
      - ~/Sites:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=localhost
      - HTTPS_METHOD=noredirect # Avoid force https redirect if the self signed certificate exist

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: local-nginx-rproxy
```

Comment: You don't have an image name in your `docker run` command. An image name is required. A docker-compose file has nothing to do with a `docker run` command, so you might have some concepts mixed up. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Hans Kilian i just edit my question and added the image, I encounter another error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameters are out of order in:

```
docker run -e jwilder/nginx-proxy  VIRTUAL_HOST=myadd.dev
```

It should be:

```
docker run -e VIRTUAL_HOST=myadd.dev jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

By going out of order, you tried to set the environment variable `jwilder/nginx-proxy` to the current environment (since there's no `=`), and then the next parameter that wasn't a value to a flag was `VIRTUAL_HOST=myadd.dev` which is not a valid image name (image names must be lower case, no `=`, and other parsing requirements). When the image name cannot be parsed, you will see `invalid reference format` because it cannot convert your "reference" to an image name.